# npm i canvas on MacOS M2

Tags: npm, next.js, canvas

When I try to install `canvas` on my nextJS 13 project, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas-postbuild.node
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node /Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@20.9.0 (node-v115 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/user1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/user1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! Package 'zlib', required by 'cairo', not found
npm ERR! Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! Package 'zlib', required by 'libpng', not found
npm ERR! Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! Package 'libffi', required by 'gobject-2.0', not found
npm ERR! Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! Package 'zlib', required by 'freetype2', not found
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/backend/Backend.cc:1:
npm ERR! ../src/backend/Backend.h:3:10: fatal error: 'cairo.h' file not found
npm ERR! #include <cairo.h>
npm ERR!          ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node" "/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v115"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node /Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node" "/Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user1/Projects/Raccord/webapp/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.9.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/user1/.npm/_logs/2023-11-27T13_44_56_912Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages with `brew`, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because there isn't a build for arm64 CPU in github, so you get a 404:

> ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz

According to [this issue on github](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1511) you will need to build it yourself:

> If you have an ARM CPU, including an Apple M1 or M2
> Prebuilds aren't available for ARM. Please see the wiki for guides on building from source. See also node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt#69.

alexscheelmeyer suggested it can be done in [two steps](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/2269#issuecomment-1636227067):

```bash
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
npm install --build-from-source canvas
```

I have tried this and it seemed to work!